Use of the pronoun 'any' with singular and plural verbs


Any is fine.
Any are fine.
I have any.
I haven't any.


Are all sentences correct?

Can you explain your doubt and show what you've already learned.  For example you could search for these phrases on the internet and link to examples of them in actual use.  The question might be closed for lack of effort.  "Is it correct" is not a good question.

Also, context matters. I can think of several wider conversations where the best sentence would be different in each case.

I can't think if a context where #3 is OK.

I'll give you a sweet, if I have any.

"Are all sentences correct?" -> "Which, if any, of these sentences are correct?"

@JamesK Your sentence is not the OP's sentence no. 3, so it doesn't show the correctness of that sentence.

You are asking about two different meanings of any.
(Choosing from a number of similar items)
"Which one would you like?" "Any [one] is fine."
"Which ones would you like?" "Any [ones] are fine." (Any means it doesn't matter which.)
(Asked whether you have something in your possession)
"I haven't any" or "I don't have any."
Here, any means a number or quantity of something. It's not correct to say
"I have any" - we say "I have one" or "I have some".
